# how to get one class transparent variable value into another class in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi i am doing one app here.user click button once means in another activity i need to perform one action,user again come back to same page agian click that same button means i need to perform  different action. i take 2 activities in activity1 i have 1 button ,i treid using one count variable in  activity1 button click that time  i incremented count variable,using putextra i get that count value into acticity2 here based on count i perform actions,but count one time is in incresed,if i come back to same activty1 then i click button  that also count is '1'only,it is not incresed to 2.so how to solve that issue any one  having idea suggest me.

```
 Activity1 .class:
 public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button b1,b2;
  int countk4=0;

   SharedPreferences share;
   String bol3;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.home1);
     b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==b1)
    {
        countk4++;
         share=getSharedPreferences("shared", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor=share.edit();

         editor.putInt("roll", countk4);

         editor.commit();

         show();
        Intent i=new Intent(Activity1 .this,Activity2.class);
        i.putExtra("k", 1);
        i.putExtra("k1", 13);
        i.putExtra("ks", val1);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
Integer val1,val2;
private void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    share=getSharedPreferences("shared", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

     val1=share.getInt("roll",0);

    }
       }

  Activity2 .class:
   public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button back;
      int countkv;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.home2);
     back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
          countkv = getIntent().getIntExtra("ks", 0); 

  if(countkv =1)
    {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hai.......i am first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   }

if(countkv =2)
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hai.......1 am second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==back)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity1.class);


        startActivity(i);
    }


}
}
}
 but above every time first toast message displayed becz countkv is every time 1 only..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Receiving side make an object of `Bundle`.

```
    Bundle myBundle = new Bundle(); // Declare above
    String temp;

    myBundle = getIntent().getIntExtra();
    temp = myBundle.getString("ks"); // temp will have the val1.
```

Hope you can get it now.

Comment: thaks for your response, here i am getting values  from ativity1 to activity2 prblm is if user again come back activity2  to activity1 that time  count variable refereshed so  that time in count '0' is there,'1' removed so if i click button again also count is incremented to 1 only not 2. that is my prblm

Comment: @user1089640: Then Declare your Variable as Public Static modifiers. Try this link ->http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/howtoaccessstaticmethod.shtml

Comment: thakyou so much i use public int countk4 that time i am not getting.but now i use public static int countk4 now i am getting result